# How to restart varnish on http request (distributed system)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, architecture, varnish

We have an api (python 2.7, flask - proxy to elasticsearch) with varnish working as a front cache. Every now and then new data is published and message is send (aws SNS with http endpoint) to api that it's time to purge cache.

On api we use varnish manager (https://github.com/justquick/python-varnish) to stop & start varnish (there is no other way to clear all cache afaik). That works but we are getting '[Errno 32] Broken pipe', because varnish is restarting while request is being processed.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: you said as far as you know, there is no other way to clear all the cache. I suggest to find a correct way, look for other methods. It's not a common practice to restart the server to clear cache. And it's even strange to restart a server while you send a request; how will you know for sure that the command succeed ?

Answer (score -1):

```
varnishadm -T 127.0.0.1:6082 url.purge .
```

or

```
ban req.http.host ~ www.domain.com
```